Inconsistent conventions in vector notations
Dealing with vectors, we usually follow the two following conventions:

CONVENTION $\boldsymbol 1$:
Vectors are denoted with an arrow; their magnitude is denoted by the same letter without the arrow.
For example, $\vec v$ is a vector and $v$ is its magnitude.


CONVENTION $\boldsymbol 2$:
The vector components of the bidimensional vector $\vec v$ are denoted by $\vec v_x$ and $\vec v_y$. The scalar components of the bidimensional vector $\vec v$ are denoted by $v_x$ and $v_y$.
The vector components are the only two vectors, one parallel to the $x$ axis and one parallel to the $y$ axis, such that $\vec v = \vec v_x + \vec v_y$:

The scalar components are the only two numbers such that $\vec v = v_x \hat x + v_y \hat y$, where $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ are the unit vectors in the direction of the $x$ axis and the $y$ axis, respectively.

These two conventions are inconsistent because, based on convention $1$, one would expect $v_x$ to be the magnitude of $\vec v_x$, which implies that $v_x \geq 0$. However, based on convention $2$, $v_x <0$ for the vector represented in the drawing.
There isn't any major conceptual difficulty here, but I keep noticing that the high school students I tutor find this extremely confusing. Do any of you know of some nice notation for vector components and scalar components that avoids this issue?

Questions about notation are generally considered off-topic, per this FAQ

The notation $\vec v_x$ (and the whole concept of “vector components”) is unfortunate, but fortunately rare (at least in my experience) once you get beyond introductory treatments of vectors.

BTW, the nomenclature “scalar components” is terrible and is just something students will eventually have to unlearn if they study physics. “Scalar” doesn’t mean “a single number”. It means “a quantity that doesn’t transform” under some coordinate transformation. The “scalar” components of a vector definitely do transform if you rotate the axes.

I've never honestly seen convention 2 used. Maybe that's just the textbooks I've read, but I personally don't know why you would ambiguously use the overarrow on both vectors and scalar vector components.

@Ghoster good point, unfortunately all high school and introductory university textbooks that I've ever come across adopt this nomenclature

@Ghoster You're right, of course. I'd prefer 'component coefficient' but I've never known anyone else to use this name.

Can any of the three voters to re-open this question explain how this is not in conflict with the FAQ that suggests such questions are off-topic?

I think the best way to avoid the ambiguity, if the students are getting confused by it, is to avoid using $v$ as the magnitude of $\vec{v}$ and instead just always use $|\vec{v}|$ to represent the magnitude.

You're not wrong, however it is somewhat cumbersome (especially in formulas) and, more importantly, I can't control what their teachers do.

@Frederico If you can't control what their teachers do then there's no point in talking about alternative notations.  But yeah, that's the tradeoff, you can decrease ambiguity by increasing cumbersomeness.

I see your point, what I meant is that avoiding using $v$ as the magnitude of $\vec v$ is probably the hardest thing to do. The convention is handy and used way too extensively. A small change in the notation for vector components would be the easiest thing, in my humble opinion. Thanks for the input though

@Federico It occurs to me that maybe you could use superscripts for components, instead of subscripts, so then $v_x$ would be the magnitude of $\vec{v_x}$ but $v^x$ would be the x-component of $\vec{v}$

I would advise the students not to confuse two different aspects when working with the vector $\vec{v}$:

If one consider its coordinates in an Euclidean plane, $\vec{v} = \left(v_x, v_y\right)$, then $v_x$ and $v_y$ can be positive or negative according to the orientation of the axes, and then $\vec{v} = v_x\hat{e}_x + v_y \hat{e}_y$;
If one consider the length of its components, these are always positive definite, due to the induced norm in the vectorial space, then $v_x := |\vec{v}_x|\geq0$.


We can write
$$\mathbf v = v \mathbf {\hat v}.$$
The coefficient of the unit vector, $\mathbf {\hat v}$, is never required to be negative, because $\mathbf {\hat v}$ is always in the direction of $\mathbf v$.
$\mathbf v = v \mathbf {\hat v}$ is of the same form as
$$\mathbf{v_x}=v_x \mathbf{e_x}.$$
But $v_x$ is sometimes required to be negative because (and this is where the trouble orignates) $\mathbf{v_x}$ is allowed to be in the opposite direction to $\mathbf{e_x}$.
$\mathbf{v_{±x}}$ would, in my opinion, be a better notation than $\mathbf{v_x}$, so we'd  rewrite the previous equation as
$$\mathbf{v_{±x}}=v_x \mathbf{e_x}.$$
Since the subscripts are different on $\mathbf{v_{±x}}$ and $v_x$ there should no longer be a temptation to assume that $v_x$ is always positive, by analogy with $\mathbf v = v \mathbf {\hat v}$.
I stop short of suggesting that you should teach the $\mathbf{v_{±x}}$ notation, as it is non-standard.

I'm sure most people here don't find it confusing, but most people here aren't 14-year-olds struggling with high school mathematics :) Your observation is a good one, though. Thank you

Interesting. In the UK, this formal stuff on vectors is generally considered to be 'A Level' material, for 16 to 18 year olds.

@Federico I've thought more about this, and have rewritten my answer. I think your question is very well posed and raises a conceptual issue that is glossed over by stigmatising it as 'opinion-based' or just about notation.

If $\vec{v_x} = v_x \hat x$ then $|\vec{v_x}| = |v_x|$ which is not necessarily equal to $v_x$, as you have pointed out. I would avoid the vector version $\vec{v_x}$ and only use the scalar version $v_x = \vec v . \hat x$.

That would certainly solve the problem. As I claim in my answer, $\vec{v_x}$ is the culprit. You suggest not using it at all [or, I suppose, using  $v_x \mathbf {\hat {e_x}}$]; I suggest renaming it.  But, as I'm sure we're both aware, $\vec{v_x}$ is too well entrenched.

With the introduction of some more maths you may use the $\Vert \vec v \Vert$ for the vector norm. and $P_x \vec v$ for the projection on the $x$-axis.
It could also be helpful to introduce the standard basis $(\vec e_x, \vec e_y)$ such that
$$
\vec v = P_x \vec v + P_y \vec v = v_x \vec e_x + v_y \vec e_y\,.
$$

Set a vector basis, and then use it to write any vector as a linear combination of the vectors of the basis: the scalar numbers of the linear combination are the components of the vector w.r.t. that basis. If some components are negative, it should not be so frightening.
Start with the "common" Cartesian basis with the $\hat{x}$ unit vector pointing to the right and $\hat{y}$ pointing upwards.
I'd save the notation $v$ for the absolute value of vector $\vec{v}$, $v := |\vec{v}|$, that is a non-negative quantity doing so.
